# Data Warehouse - duplicate dimension members for multiple divisions

Tags: sql, ssis, data-warehouse, dimension

I am fairly new to data warehousing and SSIS, but I have been tasked with populating a data warehouse with sales transaction records from 2 different divisions of the parent company. My issue...I am modifying the SSIS package that populates the Product (SKUs) dimension to accommodate for the Products that pertain to the two divisions and I have ended up with a few Product names that exist in both divisions. I need a solution to accommodate the Product list for each division in the SAME dimension table. Is this possible??

To illustrate:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hkda4n1bfs5o178/Capture.JPG?dl=0

Where 'widget_3' and 'widget_4' are **named** the same in both divisions, but they are **NOT** the same product. Just happened to be named the same. I imagine this is a common problem, but i am reluctant to make any changes to the dimension table schema before consulting with someone first.

I am working with a Product dimension table that has [MemberID] as the primary key and [Product] as a unique non clustered constraint with IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF. My first instinct was to modify the table schema to change the IGNORE_DUP_KEY to ON and rely on having a [Division] attribute to help populate the data in the fact table; use [Product] and [Division] to identify the [MemberID] on update.

Something like this??:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fjzvsh80mtp3ozs/Capture2.JPG?dl=0

Am I going down the wrong path?

Notes:
- Using SQL 2008

Comment: Your product dimension should not have anything that relates to the division.  That information should be in a fact table of some sort.

Comment: Thanks! I do include the division data in sales detail fact table but i was attempting to maintain a universal product dimension across multiple divisions. i never occurred to me that they could have the same product name. I think i will attempt to do what momobo suggested; which is to use a prefix in the case of a clash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is at the end of the day a business problem. If there is a name conflict in two department this conflict should be resolved before to present the data togheter, else a department will find that they see some sales on their product which does not belong to them.

Once understood how to treat this at the global level (for example you will have a small department prefix in case of a clash, but this has to be agreed) the problem will be automatically solved.

When the departments could not be reached or do not agree on a solution, you could have two product name column, each for every of the two department and use them togheter as PK (I will not include a division, or at least I will not show it, because it is confusing for the end users). But I do recommend to find a business solution, not a technical one.

Comment: Thank you! I complete understand and agree with your solution. I think i will try the prefix solution.